# What do I need to do as to prevent docker from downloading when I `run`?

Tags: docker

If I don’t want anything to download when I run

```
 docker run -ti --rm \
            -v /home/sable/heudiconvTest/BIDS:ro \
            -v /home/sable/heudiconvTest/qsipOutput:/out \
            pennbbl/qsiprep:latest \
            /data /out participant
```

What do I need to do? Do I just do `pull pennbbl/qsiprep:latest` and that’s it?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the commands run on the same machine, yes, that should work.

To be even safer and to make it clearer, I would use an explicit version tag, such as `0.9.0beta1`, or `0.8.0`, instead of `latest`.